# svg.js exporting svg with animation

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate, svg.js

I'm using plugin `svg.js` on my website. There is a possibility to export what I created on website to svg file. But when I do this, it only gives me a code without animation which I added.

Now it is like

```
<rect id="svg1" width="134" height="70" x="50" y="50" fill="#14a836"></rect>
```

And I need it to be with animation which I add with `.animate()` ,

for example
`rect.animate(1000, '-', 2000).move(200, 300)`,

so it probably should be like this:

```
<rect id="svg1" width="134" height="70" x="50" y="50" fill="#14a836">
    <animate> some transformations like move, rotate and so on </animate>
</rect>
```

Is there any possibility to add animation to the code? When I add `.animate()` to the export, it animates on my website, but in the code there is no change. How to do this, maybe by adding some attributes? Or maybe using another plugin?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow ! Have your tried using `animateTransform` ? 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform It can be a little tedious to make it by hand, though.

Comment: Hello! Ok, I need something like this, but it means I have to write my own function which will add `<animate>` tag inside the code given by plugin itself?

Comment: You can see in the mdn example than adding the `animateTransform` will automatically start the animation by itself. Whan you can do to start/stop it is removing and re-adding the tag.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

svg.js uses javascript to animate its elements. There is no way to export these into the svg code. However, as mentioned by other people, svg has its own way to animate its elements. The animate tag is a good point to start. Unfortunately there is no svg.js sugar to create those animations

Answer (score -1):

It looks fine to me. Maybe try to animate with [this](http://velocityjs.org/). I used it to great success.

**Edit**: Welcome to the forum!

Comment: Hello! Will I be able to make an export of svg file after using Velocity? I mean, I have svg on my website and some rects, circles, lines inside it, then I want to animate them on my website, like move rect 100px to the left and move circle 50px to the right. Then I want to play this on website by using buttons play, stop, pause. All these steps I have done by using `svg.js`, but I wasn't able to export it with animations. So will I be able to do exact same thing using Velocity plus adding animations to the export file?

Comment: I think it is possible, but to be honest I didnt try this yet, so I wouldnt know for sure.

Comment: Ok, if method given by Seblor is too hard I will try to use yours in my project. Thank you!